# Elegantly alter a list of variables: Generalization of AddTo, TimesBy, etc

Tags: language-features, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I've defined a list of variables

```
{a,b,c} = {1,2,3}
```

If I want to double them all I can do this:

```
{a,b,c} *= 2
```

The variables {a,b,c} now evaluate to {2,4,6}.
If I want to apply an arbitrary transformation function to them, I can do this:

```
{a,b,c} = f /@ {a,b,c}
```

How would you do that without specifying the list of variables twice?

(Set aside the objection that I'd probably want an array rather than a list of distinctly named variables.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
Function[Null, # = f /@ #, HoldAll][{a, b, c}]
```

For example,

```
In[1]:= 
{a,b,c}={1,2,3};
Function[Null, #=f/@#,HoldAll][{a,b,c}];
{a,b,c}

Out[3]= {f[1],f[2],f[3]}
```

Or, you can do the same without hard-coding `f`, but defining a custom `set` function. The effect of your foreach loop can be reproduced easily if you give it Listable attribute:

```
ClearAll[set];
SetAttributes[set, {HoldFirst, Listable}]
set[var_, f_] := var = f[var];
```

Example:

```
In[10]:= {a,b,c}={1,2,3};
set[{a,b,c},f1];
{a,b,c}

Out[12]= {f1[1],f1[2],f1[3]}
```

You may also want to get speed benefits for cases when your `f` is Listable, which is especially relevant now  since M8 Compile enables user-defined functions to benefit from being Listabe in terms of speed, in a way that previously only built-in functions could. All you have to do for `set` for such cases (when you are after speed and you know that `f`  is Listable) is to remove the Listable attribute of `set`.

Answer (score 0):

I hit upon an answer to this when fixing up this old question:  [ForEach loop in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160216/foreach-loop-in-mathematica)

Defining the `each` function as in the accepted answer to that question, we can answer this question with:

```
each[i_, {a,b,c}, i = f[i]]
```